Cannot Expand Datastore in ESXi 6.7 of a 4TB RAID1 Drive Configuration
I'm running ESXi 6.7 on a Dell R720 with 96GB of ram, and 2x 8-core processors. I have two 4TB drives configured in the BIOS as one disk, RAID 1.
I had a Linux VM that was utilizing about 75% of the total resources besides the storage (3.25TB of the 3.64TB-available) datastore thick partitioned - lazily zero'd, 12vCPU's, and ~70GB of RAM) as to give me a lot of computing power and storage in the VM for hardware intensive operations and private backup space. I was going to save the rest of the resources to create and utilize a small VM sandbox for opening files that could be potentially malicious. In my mind I'm keeping my compartmentalization, one for OPSEC and the other for utility. That way I don't have 4+ VMs all with limited hardware capabilities that I would otherwise have to scale one up and one or more down, to scale those hardware capabilities. My buddy wants me to keep it small and scale it up when I need more resources as to limit my VM/server blast radius. What is your opinion on this, fellow Superusers? I'm looking for side advice on that practice, but my real question is below.
Some background info:
The other day I tried to create a VeraCrypt partition (1.25TB) for backups of my cell data inside of the Primary Linux (Deb12) system (~3.25TB). I thought this would be fine because the system said I still had roughly 80% of the storage space free inside of the datastore. When creating it in my VM, the VM  crashed and gave me I/O errors. Saying my data store wasn't large enough and I needed to add more storage resources to it. Why did this happen? was it because I configured the datastore in thick-partitioning lazily-zero'd?
Trying to add more datastore space wouldn't work. I ended up deleting (not unregistering) the VM and it's accompanying datastore with the intent of starting from the ground up. I thought that if I deleted the datastore that the space would be freed up for me to repurpose it later into a new larger-or-smaller datastore (DS).
Since doing so, I created a new DS that's roughly 2.33TB in size and thin partitioned. I did thin-partitioning thinking that I could always add more storage later and the system would only use the storage that it needed inside of that allocation, allowing me to create an internal VeraCrypt partition inside of it. I then created another VM that was allocated for all of that DS's space (2.33TB). While installing it (deb12 again) I was given an error that my DS was too small again, yet ESXi says that I was only utilizing ~200GB of that storage space. However after checking in the DS browser I could see my VMDK file for the new VM was almost at peak capacity with only 72GB remaining of free space in the created DS...
I consulted my friend who's a pro at this stuff and I feel so confused as he's explaining this to me. "Don't ever delete a datastore, just increase it's capacity. Deleting a Datastore is almost the same as deleting a RAID configuration on the hardware level" Why is that?
When I try to increase space with this new one (selecting "Expand an existing VMFS datastore extent) it says it cannot change the host configuration. He also said that I "need to clean up the current DS" deleting the current VMDK file. I don't understand why it won't let me expand the DS after deleting the VM and accompanying VM files.
I found this article https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2002461 saying I have to do it from the CLI via SSH root@ESXiIP. My friend says doing it from the CLI is "only if [I] have multiple partitions" Then he asked if I'm dual booting, which I'm not. I'm wondering if there are actually partitions inside of my RAID1 config that I simply cannot see from the VeraCrypt partition I tried to form that failed upon that partition congfig.
So far he's also asked the following:
"Are you actively taking snapshots?" I said no. He says that I "...didn't delete the disk".
This confuses me because I thought I did exactly that. He wanted me to go into the DS browser and delete the disks. I did with the ISO file, and the parent directory for the VM (which included the full-capacity VMDK file) but not the ".sdd.sf" file. After doing so I deleted the VM too. Then I tried to expand the DS again. Still the same error "Cannot expand VMFS DS [DSname1] - Cannot change the host configuration". I rebooted it and that did not change the outcome.
He says "something [I] did didn't delete the VM disks, so they're taking space on the DS... Blow away that VM disk and make it smaller." I asked him "are you saying here that I should just create a new VM inside my DS that I cannot expand?" his asked me why I couldn't expand it. I explained that's "exactly what I'm asking [him]". He said to go into the configuration for storage devices and see what partitions were on the disk.
I saw that there was still a VMDK partition despite me deleting what I did. I understand that deleting a file in a partition is not the same as deleting a whole partition, so I deleted that partition. This also deleted the new DS that I just created.
I then created a new DS, with the full capacity of empty HDD space allocated for it. I then created a new VM with a Deb12 ISO and I am currently installing it but this will take a while since it's setting up LVM with encryption.
I think I answered my own question but I want a further understanding of what happened. I'm going to update this in roughly 6-8 hours to explain what happened after installing the new OS in the new VM. I think this will work.

I went into the configuration for storage devices and see what partitions were on the disk. I saw that there was still a VMDK despite me deleting what I did. So I deleted that partition. This also deleted the new DS that I just created.
I just created a new DS, with the full RAID1 HDD free capacity space allocated for it. I then created a new VM with a Deb12 ISO and I am currently installing it but this will take a while since it's setting up LVM with encryption.
I think I answered my own question. I had missed that there was a partition I couldn't see from the menus I was looking at, but I want a further understanding of what's happening here. I'm going to update this in roughly 6-8 hours to explain what happened after installing the new OS in the new VM. In the meantime I'm going to read more about ESXi basics as it seems clear to my friend and I that I don't have a basic grasp of this technology.
